# Windows Live Web Authentication on Google App Engine (GAE) using Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, windows-live

I'm struggling to get **Windows Live Web Authentication** running on **Google App Engine** (GAE) using **Python**, as I'm quite new to the language.

However there are lots of examples for Facebook and Twitter, I was wondering if anyone had come up with a solution for Windows Live yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using http://anyopenid.com which provides quite a good bridge to openid, and I was able to use this with Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the SDK you're referring to is just used for authentication, not authorization. That is, it allows you to uniquely identify a user by their Windows Live ID, but not, say, programmatically import their Hotmail contacts.

If this is the case, it would be easier to use the built-in OpenID support that's already available on both sides. The Windows Live OpenID provider is [OpenID.Live-INT.com](http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1745.entry); instructions for authenticating using OpenID on App Engine can be found @ http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html.

Comment: I've tried this approach, using:
users.create_login_url(federated_identity='openid.live-int.com',dest_url='/')

Unfortunately it is not recognising it as an openid provider, and as such is redirecting to:
http://www.google.com/gen_204?reason=EmptyURL

Which leads me to believe that Windows Live authentication requires extra "stuff" (similar to facebook's support of openid).

Comment: I think the issue actually is that openid isn't support on Windows Live yet, see: http://winliveid.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!AEE1BB0D86E23AAC!1791.entry 

The only way to currently do it is by using the "Windows Live ID Web Authentication SDK" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676633.aspx which is what I've been struggling with.

Comment: Well, that sucks. This isn't ideal, but you could use http://www.clickpass.com/ as an OpenID bridge for Windows Live accounts.